# How to prevent inserting redundant combinations in Sequelize Node.js?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I have a table for the English words: **WORDS**, and another for antonyms: **ANTONYMS**, with each word having a unique integer id in the **WORDS** table. The **ANTONYMS** table has only 2 columns: **ID_1** and **ID_2**, both referencing ids from **WORDS**.

```
const WORDS = database.define('WORDS', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelise.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    word: {
        type: Sequelise.STRING,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            is: ['^[a-z ]{2,30}$']
        },
        allowNull: false
    },
    definition: {
        type: Sequelise.TEXT,
        allowNull: true,
        validate: {
            is: ['^[a-z0-9 .,;]{10,500}$|^$', 'i']
        }
    }
})


const ANTONYMS = database.define('ANTONYMS', {
    id_1: {
        type: Sequelise.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        references: {
            model: WORDS,
            key: 'id'
        }
    },
    id_2: {
        type: Sequelise.INTEGER,
        unique: true,
        references: {
            model: WORDS,
            key: 'id'
        }
    }
})
```

Now, suppose I have two words as antonyms, one with id=1 and the other with id=2 in the **WORDS** table, and the row *(1, 2)* has already been inserted in **ANTONYMS**. How to set a constraint to prevent the user from inserting the redundant value *(2, 1)*?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a unique index in Postgres:

```
create unique index on antonyms (least(id_1, id_2), greatest(id_1, id_2));
```